# Sharing wifi over wifi

Tags: wifi, network-interface, wifi-hotspot

Im currently trying to share my wifi over wifi, on my laptop. Im running **manjaro** on my laptop and using **Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter**. And im using **linux-wifi-hotspot** to get the functionality.

When running

```
sudo create_ap wlp1s0 wlp1s0  MyAccessPoint
```

it says

```
Failed to get phy interface
ERROR: Your adapter does not support AP (master) mode
```

Running **iw list** shows **ap, ap/vlan** modes are supported.

Running **ethtool -i wlp1s0 | grep driver** show im using **driver: rtw_8822ce**.

And im sure the wifi sharing is possible in my device, cuz this functionality works in windows running on same laptop.

Any idea how to Fix this ?
Thanks!

Comment: That the Windows proprietary driver supports a given function it doesn't follow its Linux counterpart or alternative must as well.

Comment: Is there a way to use that same proprietary driver in linux to get that same functionality ?

Comment: Probably not but you can do your own research. For Realtek chipsets there are often alternative drivers maintained by enthusiasts at GitHub, PPAs (Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives), etc. Kali forums are also a very good source of information about the capabilities of chipsets and respectives drivers.